# Why doesn't Valgrind memcheck catch this UB?

Tags: c, valgrind, gcc8

Like the title say I really need help of understanding, why this code is treated on my system ( `linux mint 19`, `GCC-8.0.1`, `valgrind-3.13.0`, `c17` ) as NOT valid code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void printThis( const char *const ptr );

int main( void) {

    char a[10] = "asds";
    char b[10] = "1234567890";

    strcpy ( a, b );
    printThis( a );
}

void printThis( const char *const ptr ){
    printf("Copy completed! : %s\n", ptr );
}
```

Valgrind reports the problem here:

> ```
> ==6973== Memcheck, a memory error detector
> ==6973== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
> ==6973== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
> ==6973== Command: /home/michi/Templates/Cprogram/bin/Debug/Cprogram
> ==6973== 
> ==6973== Source and destination overlap in strcpy(0x1ffefffd14, 0x1ffefffd1e)
> ==6973==    at 0x4C32E97: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
> ==6973==    by 0x108724: main (main.c:12)
> ==6973== 
> Copy completed! : 1234567890
> ==6973== 
> ==6973== HEAP SUMMARY:
> ==6973==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==6973==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 1,024 bytes allocated
> ==6973== 
> ==6973== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
> ==6973== 
> ==6973== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
> ==6973== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
> ```

and this one as Valid code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void strcpy2(char *s, char *t);
void printThis( const char *const ptr );

int main( void) {

    char a[10] = "asds";
    char b[10] = "1234567890";

    strcpy2( a, b );
    printThis( a );
}

void strcpy2(char *s, char *t) {
    while ( ( *(s++) = *(t++) ) );
}

void printThis( const char *const ptr ){
    printf("Copy completed! : %s\n", ptr );
}
```

Valgrind output:

> ```
> ==7025== Memcheck, a memory error detector
> ==7025== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
> ==7025== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
> ==7025== Command: /home/michi/Templates/Cprogram/bin/Debug/Cprogram
> ==7025== 
> Copy completed! : 1234567890
> ==7025== 
> ==7025== HEAP SUMMARY:
> ==7025==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==7025==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 1,024 bytes allocated
> ==7025== 
> ==7025== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
> ==7025== 
> ==7025== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
> ==7025== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
> ```

Compiled with `O0`, `O1`, `O2` and `O3` and GCC flags:

`-Wpedantic -std=c17 -Wall -Wextra -Werror  -Wstrict-prototypes  -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmisleading-indentation -Wduplicated-cond -Wold-style-definition -Wconversion -Wshadow -Winit-self -Wfloat-equal -Wwrite-strings -O0 -g`

Comment: `b` needs room for 11 chars.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp You did not understand my Question,

Comment: Down voters please explain.

Comment: with "not valid code", are you referring to the message "Source and destination overlap in strcpy"?

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined.

Comment: I undid my downvote. You could make your question more clear by clearly stating the question: ***"Why doesn't valgrind catch this UB?"***

Comment: I removed the part with `strcpy`, which makes the Question dificult

Comment: If this is not a SO Question, than probably I should delete my Account here.#

Comment: Your question was unclear at first. With @HolyBlackCat's comment it makes more sense now.

Comment: @Michi and I rolled back the question because there is nothing interesting in valgrind *not* spotting a bug.

Comment: It's a valid question. Though IMO the wording is slightly unclear. At the first glance it seemed like "I use UB, but my code works properly, why?" question, which newbies ask a lot.

Comment: yes, that's why I removed that part,

Comment: @HolyBlackCat There is a hope than :D

Comment: I removed the `strcpy2` from the first excerpt - it wasn't used there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Valgrind can catch *only certain kinds of errors*. It cannot instrument the stack, hence it would not see the error with your `strcpy2`. OTOH the `strcpy` is replaced by a version that does check if the source and destination overlap - it could catch this **only** because `a + 10 == b` in **your** compiled program!

To catch this kind of error use GCC's `-fsanitize=address`:

```
% ./a.out 
=================================================================
==3368==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x7fff13832a2a at pc 0x557f05344da8 bp 0x7fff13832990 sp 0x7fff13832980
READ of size 1 at 0x7fff13832a2a thread T0
    #0 0x557f05344da7 in strcpy2 (/a.out+0xda7)
    #1 0x557f05344cca in main (/a.out+0xcca)
    #2 0x7f2d400e5b96 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)
    #3 0x557f05344a49 in _start (/a.out+0xa49)

Address 0x7fff13832a2a is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 106 in frame
    #0 0x557f05344b39 in main (/a.out+0xb39)

  This frame has 2 object(s):
    [32, 42) 'a'
    [96, 106) 'b' <== Memory access at offset 106 overflows this variable
HINT: this may be a false positive if your program uses some custom stack unwind mechanism or swapcontext
[ ... many more lines follow ... ]
```

Comment: I can not use `-fsanitize=address`  because I get [THIS](https://pastebin.com/raw/1jnqVkqH)

Comment: Strange indeed :D

Comment: @Michi Try adding `-lasan` to linker flags.

Comment: @Michi ah, I compiled it with one command only - you should add `-fsanitize=address` to the linking `gcc` too

Comment: I think I am doing something wrong here because I get `ASan runtime does not come first in initial library list; you should either link runtime to your application or manually preload it with LD_PRELOAD.`

Comment: Instead works fine with `-static-libasan`. I think, [because I get This](https://pastebin.com/raw/ux23PAnP)

Comment: The asan doesn't need valgrind

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the title to be more accurate concerning the Valgrind tool used.

Valgrind *can* detect this sort of error, but as already noted, not with `memcheck`.

If I run this example code with Valgrind `exp-sgcheck` (exp = experimental, sgcheck = stack and globals check)

```
valgrind --tool=exp-sgcheck ./so19
```

Then I get

> ==25056== Invalid read of size 1
>   ==25056==    at 0x40059D: strcpy2 (so19.c:23)
>   ==25056==    by 0x400564: main (so19.c:18)
>   ==25056==  Address 0x1ffeffed1a expected vs actual:
>   ==25056==  Expected: stack array "b" of size 10 in frame 1 back from here
>
> ==25056==  Actual:   unknown
>   ==25056==  Actual:   is 0 after Expected
>   ==25056==
>   ==25056== Invalid write of size 1
>   ==25056==    at 0x4005A0: strcpy2 (so19.c:23)
>   ==25056==    by 0x400564: main (so19.c:18)
>   ==25056==  Address 0x1ffeffed2a expected vs actual:
>   ==25056==  Expected: stack array "a" of size 10 in frame 1 back from here
>
> ==25056==  Actual:   unknown
>   ==25056==  Actual:   is 0 after Expected
>   ==25056==
>   ==25056== Invalid read of size 1
>   ==25056==    at 0x4005A2: strcpy2 (so19.c:23)
>   ==25056==    by 0x400564: main (so19.c:18)
>   ==25056==  Address 0x1ffeffed2a expected vs actual:
>   ==25056==  Expected: stack array "a" of size 10 in frame 1 back from here
>
> ==25056==  Actual:   unknown
>   ==25056==  Actual:   is 0 after Expected
>   ==25056==
>   ==25056== Invalid read of size 1
>   ==25056==    at 0x4E74C9C: vfprintf (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
>   ==25056==    by 0x4E7BFF9: printf (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
>   ==25056==    by 0x4005CD: printThis (so19.c:27)
>   ==25056==    by 0x400570: main (so19.c:19)
>   ==25056==  Address 0x1ffeffed2a expected vs actual:
>   ==25056==  Expected: stack array "a" of size 10 in frame 3 back from here
>
> ==25056==  Actual:   unknown
>   ==25056==  Actual:   is 0 after Expected
>   ==25056==
>   ==25056== Invalid read of size 1
>   ==25056==    at 0x4E9E7C0: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
>
> ==25056==    by 0x4E74FFF: vfprintf (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
>   ==25056==    by 0x4E7BFF9: printf (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
>   ==25056==    by 0x4005CD: printThis (so19.c:27)
>   ==25056==    by 0x400570: main (so19.c:19)
>   ==25056==  Address 0x1ffeffed2a expected vs actual:
>   ==25056==  Expected: stack array "a" of size 10 in frame 4 back from here
>
> ==25056==  Actual:   unknown
>   ==25056==  Actual:   is 0 after Expected

This is when compiled with debug information (`-g`). With an optimized build no errors are detected.